# finding count of a column based on the number of occurences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

I want the count of occurrences of a column on daily basis

```
new_df.head(5)
Out[165]: 
   grid_id    date_str
0   173159  2019-07-19
1   173861  2019-07-19
2   173159  2019-07-19
3   173860  2019-07-19
4   172460  2019-07-19
0   173159  2019-07-20

Expected output is:

grid_id    date_str grid_id_count
0   173159  2019-07-19 2
0   173159  2019-07-20 1
1   173861  2019-07-19 1
3   173860  2019-07-19 1
4   172460  2019-07-19 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to drop dupes based on both the cols, then `groupby` on `grid_id` and do a [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) it to a new column:

```
m=df.drop_duplicates(['grid_id','date_str']) 
final=(m.assign(grid_id_count=m.groupby('grid_id')
          .cumcount(ascending=False).add(1)).sort_index())
```

---

```
   grid_id    date_str  grid_id_count
0   173159  2019-07-19              2
0   173159  2019-07-20              1
1   173861  2019-07-19              1
3   173860  2019-07-19              1
4   172460  2019-07-19              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby all columns creating unique rows and then get the size of each group and then reset the index to get back the dataframe.

```
>>> df.groupby(['grid_id', 'date_str']).size().reset_index(name='count')
   grid_id    date_str  count
0   172460  2019-07-19  1
1   173159  2019-07-19  2
2   173159  2019-07-20  1
3   173860  2019-07-19  1
4   173861  2019-07-19  1
```

Comment: I think he does. The rows are just not in order @JonClements

Comment: Thanks for alerting. Totally missed that @help-info.de. Updated answer.